# ELT like Headway but with AE and USA culture

Tags: discussion, resource-request

For ELT literature I usually see books from the UK that put accent on British English and English literature and culture.

Is there quality ELT material with the accent on American English and USA literature and culture?

Looking for the best one from this group that I can put in class for my ELT students.

Comment: @sandalone What research have you already done on this question?

Comment: How old are your students, and how far have they gotten in their study of English?

Comment: @StoneyB Students are 15-19 years old.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a request for resources